# React-routing -> routing renders on same page even after "exact" field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I wanted to render the sign up page when its clicked in the login page. I am having some issues with the routing. The sign up page is rendering on the same page. I have only created one route on the Login page ("/signup"). My goal is to just render a new page with just the sign up details. I thought by adding exact it would fix it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import {Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import Signup from "./Signup";
import Home from "./Home";


function Login() {
  return (
<div class="login-page">
  <h2 id="projectName" class="text-center"> login. </h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <button>login</button>
        <Router>
            <p class="message">New user ->
            <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
            </p>
            <Route path="/signup" exact={true} component={Signup} />
        </Router>
      <p class = "message"> <a href="#">Forgot Password</a> or <a href="#">Forgot Username</a> </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="tagline text-center"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

  );
}

export default Login;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Login.css';

function Signup() {
  return (
<div class="login-page">
  <h2 id="projectName" class="text-center"> signup.</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First name"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last name"/>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <button>Sign up</button>
      <p class="message">Already have an account -> <a href="">Login</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="tagline text-center"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


  );
}

export default Signup;
```

[image of how the page looks with the login, and signup -> I have only set one route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCHYw.png)

Answer (score 0):

render login component through

```
<Route path="/" exact component={login} />
```

in app.js file

hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

> try this in login.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Login() {
  return (
<div class="login-page">
  <h2 id="projectName" class="text-center"> login. </h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <button>login</button>
            <p class="message">New user ->
            <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
            </p>

      <p class = "message"> <a href="#">Forgot Password</a> or <a href="#">Forgot Username</a> </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="tagline text-center"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

  );
}

export default Login;
```

> in signup.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Signup() {
  return (
<div class="login-page">
  <h2 id="projectName" class="text-center"> signup.</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First name"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last name"/>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <button>Sign up</button>
      <p class="message">Already have an account -> <a href="">Login</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="tagline text-center"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


  );
}

export default Signup;
```

> create routing component to redirect to other component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Signup from './Signup'

const Routes = () => {
    return(
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signup" exact={true} component={Signup} />
      </Switch>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```